# convert a string to object in javascript like regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have the following variable

```
var characters = /[-()&]/
```

and i have a string like this

```
var characters_string = "/[-()&]/"
```

this string is result from array and join, because i need to add news variables, so, i need to convert characters_string to a object like characters because is not working with characters_string
because when i use in this line

```
var filter_d = info.split(/[.,%]/)
```

and i use it like this

```
var filter_d = info.split(characters_string)
```

but i get error

thanks

Comment: `new RegExp(characters_string)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new RegExp`,but you need delete the "/" at the start and the end of the string

```
new RegExp(characters_string.slice(1, -1))
```